# Reference resource name in Terraform

Tags: terraform, resources

Let's define the following resource

```
    resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "foobar" {
    alarm_name                = "terraform-test-foobar5"
    comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
    evaluation_periods        = "2"
    metric_name               = "CPUUtilization"
    namespace                 = "AWS/EC2"
    period                    = "120"
    statistic                 = "Average"
    threshold                 = "80"
    alarm_description         = "This metric monitors ec2 cpu utilization"
    insufficient_data_actions = []
}
```

Is it possible to reference the name of the resource within that resource?
I mean something like `resource.name`.

Thanks

Comment: As long as the value isn't calculated you should be able to, e.g. your example could use alarm_description = "This metric monitors ec2 cpu utilization ${aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.foobar.alarm_name}"

Comment: Something like resource referencing itself?

Comment: @MarkoE exactly.

Comment: That is not possible. There are some exceptional cases where `self` can be used but I do not think it will work for this code snippet.